# Swipe a viewcontroller as Muliplepage in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to swipe a viewcontroller shows as muliple page, only data changing when we do swipe.
please help me out, how should i achieve this task.

Regards
Sri

Answer (score 1):

Apple have a great tutorial from this year's WWDC which shows how to do a paging UIScrollView, which I think is what you want. The example code is here:

http://connect.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/MemberSite.woa/wa/getSoftware?code=y&source=x&bundleID=20645

And the video of the presentation (which explains a how it works very well) here:

http://insideapple.apple.com/redir/cbx-cgi.do?v=2&la=en&lc=&a=kGSol9sgPHP%2BtlWtLp%2BEP%2FnxnZarjWJglPBZRHd3oDbACudP51JNGS8KlsFgxZto9X%2BTsnqSbeUSWX0doe%2Fzv%2FN5XV55%2FomsyfRgFBysOnIVggO%2Fn2p%2BiweDK%2F%2FmsIXj

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [github](https://github.com/nicktmro/NPGesturedViewController) project. Just replace the Example View Controller with your own.